# How to create a list of customers who buy less over time?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have customer transactions data as shown below and need to create a list of only those customers whose total ordered units is consistently lesser than the previous order. i.e.Total Qty purchased in the nth order is less than Total Qty purchased in n-1 th order, and the next previous order is also less. Another way to say it, list the customers buy fewer units as time goes forward.

```
Custid  date    units
123 28-03-17    100
123 27-03-17    100
123 26-03-17    100
999 25-03-17    10
999 24-03-17    20
893 24-03-17    39
893 28-03-17    48
893 24-03-17    10
893 19-03-17    75
893 12-02-17    10
```

Such that the output of the code should be customer 999.

I initially thought of using the lag function after sorting the transactions and then using a conditional statement but the number of transactions varies across customers.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lag()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select custid
from (select t.*,
             lag(units) over (partition by custid order by date) as prev_units
      from t
     ) t 
group by custid
having sum(case when units >= pev_units then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```